# Change the width of the background image using CSS

Tags: css, background-image, background-size

I'm having the following code:

```
#main {
  background: url(../../images/achtergrond.png) center top repeat-y;
}
```

Is it possible to change the width of the background image?

Comment: Not in the background, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property to do so...

```
#main {
    background-size: 20px 50px;
    /* Other properties goes here */
}
```

Where the first parameter is X axis or say for horizontal and the other is for Y axis or vertical.

So if you want to change the `width` you need to set the Y parameter to the units you want and the X you can set to `auto`

Also, what you are using is a short hand property, I provided you the specific one so that you can get what I did, you can surely integrate the `background-size` in your short hand declaration.